# Binding other than 127.0.0.1 loopback addresses

Tags: python, windows, sockets, udp

Why can't I send data via UDP socket, when I bind it to e.g. 127.0.0.2, instead of 127.0.0.1? Receiving seems to work

This is my receiving end

```
>>> import socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
>>> sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 6666))
>>> sock.recvfrom(1024)
('01', ('127.0.0.1', 7777))
```

And this is how I send the data

```
>>> sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
>>> sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 7777))
>>> sock.sendto(b'01',('127.0.0.1',6666))
2
```

Now if in sending I say like

```
>>> sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
>>> sock.bind(('127.0.0.2', 7777))
>>> sock.sendto(b'01',('127.0.0.1',6666))
2
```

Nothing happens in receiving end. sendto returns 2, just like with .1 address, but nothing just arrives to receiving end. To make this more strange, if I bind/receive 127.0.0.2/6666, it can receive data just fine. But again, not if I send the data from 127.0.0.2

This is Python 2.7.5 and I run it on windows 7. I am trying to build MT environment, where I could simulate connections to multiple IP addresses, within same computer. I have no idea whether this is a python feature or windows or maybe user error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sock.recvfrom(1024)` again to receive next 1024 Bytes data from the socket buffer.

Then you will see `(b'01', ('127.0.0.2', 7777))` in the receiving end.

Tell me if it works.

**EDIT:**

Server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- 

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 6666))
while 1:
    data = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print data
```

client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import socket

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 7777))
sock.sendto(b'01',('127.0.0.1',6666))

sock.close()
sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
sock.bind(('127.0.0.2', 7777))
sock.sendto(b'02',('127.0.0.1',6666))
sock.close()
```

I can get

```
('01', ('127.0.0.1', 7777))
('02', ('127.0.0.2', 7777))
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, I did that of course.I also found some rawcap.exe program that apparently sniffs loopback IF. I can see with that tool bytes sent from .1 address, but not from .2 address. So one might draw the conclusion that it is the sending end that does not work...

Comment: @fastfox You mean you didn't even see the message in the receiving end? But it works from my side. Maybe you need to close the socket binding (127.0.0.1, 7777) first and then open another terminal and create a new socket binding to (127.0.0.2, 7777), then try again.

Comment: Yes, I mean that I just see nothing in the receiving end, if the sender is something else than 127.0.0.1. That is very strange if it actually works for you. I've tried to reopen interpreters and even rebooting couple times. I tried the same lines in some linux machine and worked just fine there.

Comment: @fastfox I've updated my answer. Try again and tell me what happened.

Comment: Noup. I just get the '01'. But, now when I played around with your script, I realized that if I add this 'sock.sendto(b'01',('127.0.0.2',7777))' to your server.py, just after 'bind', I get both '01' and '02' packets! Almost as if there is somekind of internal firewall that blocks .2 -> .1, until it has been opened from .1 -> .2.

Comment: @fastfox Maybe you should check firewall settings like iptables.